# Как можно ускорить работу программы?

Tags: python, алгоритм, производительность, олимпиада, простые-числа

в промежутке от start до finish (включительно) ищет все простые числа

```
    start, finish = map(int, input().split())
    count = 0
    for i in range(start, finish + 1):
        c = 2
        while c ** 2 < i and i % c != 0:
            c += 1
        if c ** 2 > i:
            print(i)
            count += 1
    if count == 0:
        print('Absent')
```

Comment: Вот вы выбрали тэг `простые числа`. Если посмотреть вопросы и ответы по этой теме, можно что-то подходящее подыскать

Comment: А что известно о диапазоне? Может, проще решетом получить список подходящих простых и проверять делимость на них? Ну и, как минимум, проверять только нечетные, и `c+=2` — уже ускорение в 2 раза...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот 2 быстрых способа :)

**способ 1:**

```
import gmpy2

primes = [i for i in range(start, finish + 1) if gmpy2.is_prime(i)]
```

**способ 2 (быстрее на 25%):**

```
import gmpy2

primes2 = []
p = start - 1
while p <= finish:
    p = gmpy2.next_prime(p)
    if p <= finish:
        primes2.append(p)
```

**способ 3 (без библиотек):**

используем решето Эратосфена

```
primes = []
sieve = [0] * n

for i in range(2, n):
    if sieve[i] == 0:
        primes.append(i)
        if i * i <= n:
            for j in range(i * i, n, i):
                sieve[j] = 1
```

**способ 3+ (тоже самое решето, но получше)**

```
def get_primes(n):
    n = b + 1
    size = n//2
    sieve = [1]*size
    limit = int(n**0.5)
    for i in range(1, limit):
        if sieve[i]:
            val = 2*i+1
            tmp = ((size-1) - i)//val
            sieve[i+val::val] = [0]*tmp
    return [2] + [i*2+1 for i, v in enumerate(sieve) if v and i > 0]
```

Comment: Нельзя использовать никакие модули =(( Это академическая задача

Comment: тогда решето Эратосфена - привел код